# Retain values from a multiselect dropdownlist after page refresh using jquery chosen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-chosen

```
        <div>
          Projects
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.ProjectMasterId, new MultiSelectList(Model.ProjectsList, "Value", "Text", Model.ProjectMasterId),
           new { @class = "chosen-projects", multiple = "multiple" })
        </div>
        <div class="button" style="padding-left:18px">
            <input type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-warning" value="Search" name="Search" />`enter code here`

        </div>
```

Here i have the data from the model and enumerated it using lists

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".chosen-projects").chosen({ width: "85%" });
    });
   </script>
```

The script for jquery chosen

I am unable to see the values that i selected after the submit button is clicked, i need to see the values that i have selected but are gone after the page refresh,

I have searched many but an explanation would be very helpful since i am new to this whole.

Answer (score 0):

Changed dropdown for multiselect to listbox control and works like a charm